Best way to sort the information
I have a list of items I am trying to use IF AND to sort however i am struggling to figure it out with my limited knowledge of Excel. I would like to use formatting to reflect the end result as highlighted in the second image. The colour represents Yes = green and No = Yellow
This is the data

This is the information i would liek to display


It's possible to do with some formulas and conditional formatting, but it's not very simple, so I'm not sure if it's for your "limited knowledge of Excel"

What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

You could combine a Pivot Table with conditional formatting, and then hide the Yes.No column.

Using addresses from the screenshot below you can apply formulas:
In A16:
=UNIQUE(A2:A11)

In B15:
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B11))

In B16:
=FILTER($C$2:$C$11,($A16=$A$2:$A$11)*(B$15=$B$2:$B$11),"")

Copy over the entire range.
Conditional format for the range B16:F22 and green colour:
=FILTER($D$2:$D$11,($A16=$A$2:$A$11)*(B$15=$B$2:$B$11),"")="yes"

The same with "no" for yellow.


This is really 2 questions in one:

Pivot the values by name/colour. Several options here, but if you have access to PIVOTBY (for Beta Insiders), this is a logic choice:
=PIVOTBY(A2:A11,B2:B11,C2:C11,SUM,,0,,0)
Else, using  Office 365 you could use:
=LET(data,  A2:D11,
     name,  INDEX(data,,1),
     colour,INDEX(data,,2),
     dates, INDEX(data,,3),
     un,    UNIQUE(name),
     uc,    UNIQUE(colour),
VSTACK(
       HSTACK("",
              TOROW(uc)),
       HSTACK(un,
              MAKEARRAY(ROWS(un),ROWS(uc),
                 LAMBDA(r,c,
                        XLOOKUP(INDEX(un,r,)&"|"&INDEX(uc,c,),name&"|"&colour,dates,""))))))


Conditional formatting by lookup value. If the spill range is starts in H1, for yes select the spill range and use: =IF(H1,XLOOKUP($H1&H1,$A$2:$A$11&$C$2:$C$11,$D$2:$D$11))="yes" and format green.
for no copy the rule and change yes to no and format yellow.




You may import your data range into Excel Power Query.
Then select the "Color" column, click "Transform" tab > Pivot Column in Any Column group > Select "Date" for Values Column, choose "Don't Aggregate" under Advanced options.

Right click on "Yes.No" column, remove it.

Then load query to sheet as a table.
Yellow: =FILTER($D$2:$D$11,($H2=$A$2:$A$11)*(I$1=$B$2:$B$11),"")="no"
Green: =FILTER($D$2:$D$11,($H2=$A$2:$A$11)*(I$1=$B$2:$B$11),"")="yes"

